# What does this error mean?: Operating system version {0} is too low. You need at least version {2}

Tags: sap

Please can someone tell me what this means?:

```
<!--LOGHEADER[START]/-->
<!--HELP[Manual modification of the header may cause parsing problem!]/-->
<!--LOGGINGVERSION[1.5.3.7185 - 630]/-->
<!--NAME[T:\\usr\\sap\\jupgrade\\log\\CHECKS.LOG]/-->
<!--PATTERN[CHECKS.LOG]/-->
<!--FORMATTER[com.sap.tc.logging.ListFormatter]/-->
<!--ENCODING[UTF8]/-->
<!--LOGHEADER[END]/-->
#1.5#C0000A25023100000000425359C9B9CA0004A51CC6D5CF78#1307442920411#/System/Server/Upgrade/Checks##com.sap.sdt.j2ee.phases.PhaseTypeCheckOSDB.handleReason(PhaseTypeCheckOSDB.java:297)#######Thread[main,5,main]##0#0#Error#1#com.sap.sdt.j2ee.phases.PhaseTypeCheckOSDB.handleReason(PhaseTypeCheckOSDB.java:297)#Java###Operating system version {0} is too low. You need at least version {2}.#4#AMD64 5.2#MSS 10.0.2734#[AMD64 6.0,AMD64 6.0]##
```

It occurs in the **\usr\sap\jupgrade\log\CHECKS.LOG** file, when I run the 'General Checks' stage of the' PREPARE Module Status' program.

I am trying to patch a SAP 7.01 SAP Portal to EHP2. The server is running Windows 2003 SP2, MS SQL Server 2008 SP1.

I believe that the versions of both the OS and DB are sufficient for EHP2. The upgrade will use a 7.2 kernel and I think that the software versions are sufficient for that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a poor error message.

In fact, I should have been using the Enhancement Package installer (SAPehpi). The document for that is here:

- http://service.sap.com/instguides
- SAP NetWeaver
- SAP NetWeaver 7.0 (2004s)
- Maintenance
- Enhancement Package Installation on Existing SAP Systems
- SAP Enhancement Package Installation on Java Systems (using SAPehpi)